# Windows 8.1 Scheduled Task on Idle Not Waiting for Specified Time

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks

I have created a Scheduled Task to run after 30 minutes of inactivity. Apparently Windows 8 considers the system idle after four minutes of no user activity (see [Task Idle Conditions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I have disabled the screensaver and the Power Option to turn off monitors (these are both 'idle' states).

In my Task I have a Trigger defined for On Idle and in Conditions I have checked Start the task only if the computer is idle for [30 minutes]. However, during testing it seems that the Task is run after approximately five minutes of inactivity (it could be four minutes, I haven't precisely clocked it to the second). For testing I ran:

```
time /t
```

as the Task's Action and sat and waited to see what would happen. Sure enough it prints the time five minutes after I stopped playing with the mouse.

My question is how can I get Windows 8.1 to respect the 30 minute timeout I want? I want to have the Action run 30 minutes after I get up and leave the PC, not four/five minutes.

As requested the Conditions tab

[image]

Comment: Could you specify the exact settings you're using in the Conditions tab?

Comment: Included a link to an image of the Conditions tab.

Comment: What is the command you are running?  Is it just DATE /T ?

Comment: Right now I am just running date /t, but the Action shouldn't matter - the Task is triggering too early (in my opinion).

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar behavior - Task Scheduler doesn't seem to care about the idle time (Windows 8.1).

Comment: Same issue on 10